# Maven : No compile errors but still cant find symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a pretty basic maven project in eclipse. I updated the pom with some new dependencies and after that i cant do

`mvn clean install`

or

`mvn compile`

as each time i get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project commons: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /path/to/my/class:[5,40] package org.springframework.test.context does not exist
[ERROR] /path/to/my/class:[8,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class ActiveProfiles
```

but i have the required dependency in my pom i.e.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

i know that the scope is test

`<scope>test</scope>`

but that should not matter during the build right? Most importantly, i do not see any compilation errors in the IDE. I am using eclipse mars.

How can i build successfully?

Comment: Is your class in `src/test/java`?

Comment: *that should not matter during the build right*: of course it matters. Dependencies of the scope test are used to compile the test classes, not the production classes. Eclipse is unable to do the distinction, that's why you don't have problems in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the **< scope >test< /scope >** section. Or use **compile** scope.

> **test**
>   This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.

Also check this [documentation for Maven Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Comment: Glad it helped !!

Comment: This is because of a limitation in Eclipse so the correct maven behavior cannot be emulated 100%.